Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(), js engine: hermes
GETTING ISSUE WITH FIREBASE MESSEING AND FIREBASE APP

using react-native version 0.73.0. also add complete the all steps as per firebase documents so any can help?.
i have try so many steps foe resolved this issue but not getting anything.
if anything i miss which is not available in documents then let me know it's very help full for me.

